# SQL Developer 3.0 Case statement

Tags: sql

Need Help in creating the query where there are multiple conditions for assigning various health care levels of care:

In this scenario, for TSS services (one specific level of care) the combinations can be standalone Proc code or Proc code plus modifiers.   Not sure how to include multiple scenarios where they all equate to TSS.

Here is my current query:

```
Select member_id, claim_ID, payment_amount, provider_name, procedure_code, modifier_code
Case
When procedure_code In ('H0021', 'H0022) or procedure code in ('H0023') and modifier_code in ('HW", 'TU') then 'TSS"
when procedure_code In ('H0024') or procedure_code in ('H0024') and modifier in ('HA') then 'BSC'
else 'others'
end as levelofcare
from papa.dwh_claims
```

Comment: So what exactly is the problem with this query?

Comment: You should format your code by adding the corresponding parentheses in OR, AND.

Comment: There is a quote missing at `'H0022` and a quote mismatch at `'HW"` and `'TSS"`. `AND` / `OR` should not be a problem because `AND` has precedence over `OR`. But for readability parentheses would be good anyway.

Comment: I am not extremely proficient in writing SQL statements but when I run the query the program not does not assign the levels of care accurately.    How do you write the syntax to state that that this condition (procedure code in this case) or a combination of procedure code plus a modifier code can also equal TSS?

Comment: Yes I was not very careful in typing my program from work computer so may be missing quotes but do you need to put parenthesis in situations where there are multiple conditions that equal the same value?

Comment: Can someone send me a sample of what should the OR and AND look like so I can replicate?

Comment: Should I incorporate IF THEN logic?

Comment: It is still unclear why you think the query is not working for you. You should show sample data, results given by the query and results you actually want. With the little information given, we cannot help you. (As an indicator: SQL questions usually get answers within few minutes. When they don't there is probably something wrong with the request.)

Comment: You'd use parentheses to group boolean expressions. For instance you want `procedure_code in ('H0021', 'H0022')` to result in `'TSS'`. You also want `procedure code in ('H0023')` combined with `modifier_code in ('HW', 'TU')` to result in `'TSS'`. The latter is a combination of boolean expressions and should be grouped with parentheses: `procedure_code in ('H0021', 'H0022') or (procedure code in ('H0023')` and `modifier_code in ('HW', 'TU'))`. However, as `AND` has precedence over `OR` anyway, the parentheses don't change anything, they only make this more readable.